# Inconsistent line endings using git-svn with commits from both VCS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, git, git-svn, line-endings

I have a remote SVN repository and a local git repository. Using git-svn I have linked git to SVN and am successfully using `git svn rebase`, `git svn dcommit` to pull and push to the remote SVN repository.

However, when other people check out my previously-git-edited files with `SVN` and try to open them in VS2010, they receive a dialog telling them the line endings are inconsistent.

I've read a few things about the **`core.safecrlf`** option in git config, but would that fix my issue? I have a number of other people checking in, but we're all running windows - I figured the line endings would be the same?

Would setting `core.safecrlf` preserve the same type of line ends on checkout and on commit?

Comment: stop breaking my line endings may!

Answer (score 4):

I have been dealing with this same issue lately.  By default, Git on Windows sets **core.autocrlf = true**.  What happens is that your files are checked out from the SVN repo with CRLF line endings, but are committed with unix-style (LF) line endings.  When you **dcommit** those changes, I believe the files are pushed to the SVN server with the unix-style line endings as well.  Now when someone checks out those files using SVN, no line ending conversion is performed.

You can set **core.autocrlf = false** so that no conversion is done.  If you are all working in Windows, you shouldn't have any problems.  If you are sharing the SVN repo with *nix users, then it is likely that you'll start having inconsistencies.  This is the reason for the autocrlf option.  The repos should remain consistent, and since Linux doesn't like to play nicely with CRLF, this autocrlf should be set to true.

Comment: Just a note that once the setting has been changed you should verify all line ending are as you expect them.  To do this you should make the change to the core.autocrlf property and then pull the Git repo.  Now check the line endings of your files. Finally, commit any changes as a single commit. From that point forward you just need to verify that you change this value for any new environments (new machines, reinstalls, etc) that you setup.

Answer (score 1):

Line endings problem is a well-known headache of git-svn. I would recommend to use [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) to work with your repository. I respects svn:eol-style value to use correct EOL in Git (translating to it to a corresponding .gitattirbutes value). You may also control svn:eol-style value on pushing to SVN by appropriate changes .gitattirbutes.

If you have an access to the server another approach is possible: just install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) into your SVN server. Then a linked Git repository will be created on the server such that every push to it will be automatically translated to SVN and vice versa.  It also translates svn:eol-style to .gitattirbutes.

So I would recommend one of these solutions, but not git-svn that is (as I know) painfully slow on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a GitHub article that describes your choices for handling end of line characters in Git:

https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

Essentially Git helps convert EOL on different OS's.  SVN has similar functionality.  You will need to ensure that they are set in a consistent manner.